# Conditional Formatting with switch

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, report-builder2.0

This is the design view of my matrix, it uses a series of datasets and the expressions use a lookup

[image]

This is the report when it has ran.  I want to add some conditional formatting to the end column

[image]

The conditional formatting is dependent on the name of the person and then what total is in that field. Below is what I have tried. I would expect only Hilary's cell to show a colour. However others are appearing as green.

```
 =switch(Fields!Name.value = "Hilary" and 
  reportitems!Textbox62.value >=0 and reportitems!Textbox62.value <= 9,"#fd6767", 
  reportitems!Textbox62.value >=10 and reportitems!Textbox62.value <=19, "#f8d3a9", 
  reportitems!Textbox62.value >= 20 and reportitems!Textbox62.value <=100,"LightGreen")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, all other names should get the cell with a blank background, shouldn't they ?
In this case, you have to add the condition "Name=Hilary" for each row. In your expression, this one is just related to the first row.
Try this one:

```
=switch(
  Fields!Name.value = "Hilary" and reportitems!Textbox62.value >=0 and reportitems!Textbox62.value <= 9,"#fd6767", 
  Fields!Name.value = "Hilary" and reportitems!Textbox62.value >=10 and reportitems!Textbox62.value <=19, "#f8d3a9", 
  Fields!Name.value = "Hilary" and reportitems!Textbox62.value >= 20 and reportitems!Textbox62.value <=100,"LightGreen")
```

Comment: Spot on! frustrated with myself for not working that out, thank you

Comment: keep in mind that your expression will change the background color only if the value is between 0 and 100. 
You're not taking account negative value or value higher than 100